# Why does EntityType return the namespace of the context, but not of the entity?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I need to get CLR entity type from `EntityType.FullName` but it is incorrect.

Our models are placed in the namespace different from the context's one.

When I retrieve `EntityType.FullName` it returns  `<ContextNamespace>.<EntityName>`, but not `<EntityNamespace>.<EntityName>`. Is it a feature? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual...wrong assumptions. CLR types are available in `DataSpace.OSpace`.
And EntityType from `CSpace` contains seemingly 'virtual' namespace, somewhat unrelated to that of CLR.

Rowan has written a good [post](http://romiller.com/2014/04/08/ef6-1-mapping-between-types-tables/) about getting metadata for a given type.

It looks like Name is the only thing what connects CLR type with EntityType.
I've tried to add new `DbSet` with the entity coming from different namespace but having the same class name. EF just threw `InvalidOperationException`.